# Regex to match specific domain format

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a specific domain name, the domain is:

`example-123.domain.com`
or
`another-51392.domain.com`

Basically It's a string, followed by a hyphen, followed by numbers, then the `domain.com`.

I've tried a few different patterns, but nothing close.  Any ideas how I can do this? Thank you

Comment: What patterns did you try?

Comment: what means match? what part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this it?

```js
var str = "another-51392.domain.com domain.com example-123.domain.com google.com www.facebook.com another21141-aaa.domain.com another-51392.domainXcom";

var pattern = /(\w+-\d+\.domain\.com)/gm;

console.log( str.match( pattern ) );
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you